# Why is my React App not rendering inside of my root div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am struggling to figure out why my react app will not render within my root div element. I have spent hours googling narrowing down my issue to my index.html being shown in the console but nothing else is rendering even though it appears to be set up correctly. This is on the Firefox browser so I am trying to understand why it is not displaying.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```jsx
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App.jsx'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
);
```

```jsx
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Login from './components/Login';
import AccountCreation from './components/AccountCreation';
import AddNewGame from './components/AddNewGame';
import GameStats from './components/GameStats';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
        <Route path='/accountcreation' element={<AccountCreation />} />
        <Route path='/addnewgame' element={<AddNewGame />} />
        <Route path='/gamestats' element={<GameStats />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Code looks ok. For starters you can narrow it down by removing react router and rendering a basic react component.

Comment: Do you have all of that code in a single file?  Or are they separate files?  If separate, please edit the post to make that clear.  If they are a single file...that is your problem...you want to separate them.

Comment: Any errors reported in your browser console?

Comment: The only error that populates in my browser code is this:                                                      Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default                                                  but all my components are being export default

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after stepping away and coming back, I had not defined each component and yet was trying to import them causing this error. I now am able to see my components after defining each one!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).